# Python sequence cluster exercise

Tags: python, algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am working through an exercise in my textbook and implementing the code in Python to practice dynamic programming. I feel like I am right on the edge of figuring it out, but after many hours, I come here for help.

Basically, my code is going through a list of values `x`, and given a `k`, breaks that list into `k` clusters based on calculating the minimum sum of squared errors (SSE) for a particular cluster.

The code creates a table, calculating the SSE for 1 cluster, 2 clusters, ..., k clusters, if we were to put the cluster parentheses around all variations of values within `list[0:1]`, `list[0:2]`, `list[0:3]`, ..., `list[0:n]`, and choosing the minimum SSE for that particular step in the table.

For example:

Given `x= [7,6,9,15,18,17,30,28,29]` and `k=3`

we would return clusters `(7,6,9)(15,18,17)(30,28,29)`, which would translate to sum of squared error equal to `(4.666)(4.666)(2)` for each cluster. So our max SSE would be `4.666` for that clustering on that list.

Now when I try it on my second list `x = [52, 101, 103, 101, 6, 5, 7]`, I should get clustering `(52)(101, 103, 101)(6, 5, 7)`, which should give `(0)(2.666)(2)` or a max of `2.666`, but am not getting that. I believe the error lives in the  `def f(s, j_down, t)` for the 2nd return statement, and how I increment `s` and `t`. Hopefully, I have not made a silly mistake!

```
def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

def sum_square(x):
    if isinstance(x, (int,)):
        return 0
    w = 0
    for i in x:
        w += (i - mean(x))**2
    return w

def f(s, j_down, t):
    if not r[s][j_down] and r[s][j_down] != 0:
        return sum_square(x[:t - s])

    return max(r[s][j_down], sum_square(x[:t-s]))

def get_min_f_and_s(j_down, t):
    """ range s from 1 to t-1 and set s to minimize f(s)
    """
    items = [(s, f(s, j_down, t)) for s in range(t)]
    s, min_f = min(items, key=lambda x:x[1])
    return s, min_f

def seq_out(n,k):
    for j in range(k):
        if j == 0:
            for t in range(n):
                r[t][j] = sum_square(x[:t+1])

                c[t][j] = x[:t+1]
        else:
            for t in range(1, n):
                s, min_f = get_min_f_and_s(j - 1, t)
                r[t][j] = min_f
                c[t][j] = [c[s][j - 1]] + x[s+1:t+1]

    print('the max SSE is: {}'.format(r[-1][-1]))
    print('the cluster centers are: {}'.format(c[-1][-1]))

#x = [7,6,9,15,18,17,30,28,29]    
x = [52, 101, 103, 101, 6, 5, 7]
k = 3
n = len(x)

r = [[[] for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(n)]
c = [[[] for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(n)]

print(seq_out(n,k))
print(r)
print(c)
```

Edit: Question layout

Given a sequence `X = [x_1, x_2, ... x_n]` and integer `k > 1`, partition `X` into clusters `C_1,..., C_k` of sizes `n_1, ..., n_k`, so that the sum of squared errors is minimized.

Comment: You should probably write mathematically what your DP recurrence is that you’re trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you define what recursion you used, it's hard to really be sure what you're trying to implement. I took a look at the fundamental problem you are solving, though, and defined a recurrence that will work. I assume here we have some sequence $d(i)$ with $n$ components that starts with indexing at $1$. Running with this, the minimum cost clustering such that you get exactly $k$ clusters can be expressed with the recurrence

\begin{align}
f(i,j) &= \begin{cases} 
\infty & (i=0 \land j \neq k+1) \lor (i \neq 0 \land j = k+1) \\
0 & (i = 0 \land j = k+1) \\
\text{cost}(1,i) & j = k\\
\min_{1 \leq l \leq i} f(l-1, j+1) + \text{cost}(l,i) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where the $\text{cost}(i,j)$ cost function returns the cluster cost of viewing elements $i$ to $j$ in the sequence as a cluster. We can define the cluster cost as

\begin{align}
\text{cost}(i,j) &= \sum_{s = i}^j \left(d(s) - \mu(i,j)\right)^2 \\
\text{where }\mu(i,j) &= \frac{1}{j - i + 1}\sum_{t = i}^j d(t)
\end{align}

Using these definitions, one can implement the recurrence however they want and to find $f$. The simplest is a recursion with memoization built in but I tend to look for where the know elements are in $f(i,j)$ off the bat and using those to fill in the other quantities more efficiently. Regardless of how you do it, you can fill in $f$ and then use the table to find the optimal $k$ clusters by using $\arg \min_{1 \leq l \leq i} f(l-1, j+1) + \text{cost}(l,i)$ with the starting indices $i = n$ and $j = 1$.

I wrote a code in Python that implements this solution, which you can compare against if desired

```
#import useful libs
import numpy as np

# problem is found here: 
# https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/31244/python-sequence-cluster-exercise

# define efficient representation of cluster cost
class cluster_cost:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.n = len(data)
        self.ss_x = np.cumsum(data)    # subset sum of x
        self.ss_x2= np.cumsum(data**2) # subset sum of x^2

    def cost(self, i, j):
        if i == 0:
            dx = self.ss_x[j]
            dx2= self.ss_x2[j]
        else:
            dx = self.ss_x[j] - self.ss_x[i-1]
            dx2= self.ss_x2[j] - self.ss_x2[i-1]
        mean = dx/(j-i+1)
        return dx2  + (j-i+1)*mean**2 - 2.0*mean*dx



def dp_soln(data, k):

    # define cluster cost function
    cc = cluster_cost(data)

    # get number of elements in data
    n = cc.n

    # init the DP cost table
    f = np.full((n+1,k+2), np.inf)

    # construct f[i,j] for all i and j
    # init for j = k+1
    f[0,k+1] = 0

    # init for j <= k
    for j in range(k, 0, -1):
        for i in range(1,n+1):

            # get the min cost option
            best = np.inf
            for l in range(1, i+1):
                best = np.min([best, f[l-1,j+1] + cc.cost(l-1,i-1)])

            # set best cost to DP table
            f[i,j] = best

    # solve for the optimal clustering
    # using cost table from DP algo
    partition_indices = []
    partition = []

    # set initial state indices to (n,1)
    i = n
    j = 1

    # loop until k clusters found
    while j <= k:

        # find argmin that matches DP value
        best = np.inf
        best_idx = 1
        for l in range(1, i+1):
            bestn = np.abs( f[i,j] - f[l-1,j+1] - cc.cost(l-1,i-1) )
            if( bestn < best ):
                best_idx = l
                best = bestn

        # get the next partition based on argmin
        partition_indices.append((i-1, best_idx-1))
        partition.append(data[(best_idx-1):i])

        # update indices
        i = best_idx - 1
        j = j + 1

    # return the partition indices and partition
    return (partition_indices, partition)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = 3
    data = np.array([7, 6, 9, 15, 18, 17, 30, 28, 29])
    (indices, part) = dp_soln(data, k)
    print(indices)
    print(part)
```

The above sample $k$ and $\text{data}$ return the expected output when run:

```
[(8, 6), (5, 3), (2, 0)]
[array([30, 28, 29]), array([15, 18, 17]), array([7, 6, 9])]
```